# How to use the open and close methods in Side bar element.io vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I´m using element.eleme.io with vue in my app, so there is a NavMenu component and I want to close a submenu when another is open, this component has a close method that close a specific submenu, but I don´t know how to use it.

This is my code

```
<el-menu
        background-color="transparent"
        @open="handleOpen"
        @close="handleClose"
        @select="subMenuSeleccionado"
        :default-active="activo">
        <el-submenu :index="categoria.slug" v-for="(categoria,indexCategoria) in categoriasOrdenadas"
                    :key="indexCategoria">
            <template slot="title">
                <i class="el-icon-setting"></i> <span>{{categoria.nombre}}</span>
            </template>
            <el-menu-item-group v-for="(subcategoria, indexSubcategoria) in categoria.categoriasHijas"
                                :key="subcategoria.slug">
                <el-menu-item :index="subcategoria.slug">{{subcategoria.nombre}}</el-menu-item>
            </el-menu-item-group>

        </el-submenu>
    </el-menu>
```

and in the handleOpen function I tried something like this but it dosn´t works

```
 methods: {
        handleOpen(key) {
            this.$el.close('key1');
        },
```

and this is the page
https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation it says that the menu accepts a prop called `unique-opened` which is used to check whether only one sub-menu can be active at a time and by default it is set to `false`
You can just pass it as true like this:

```
<el-menu :unique-opened="true" ...
```

Comment: thanks alot, I was only focus on the close method that I didn´t read correctly the documentation